# ReceivedMIDISystemCommand() is not called when receiving sysex messaged in Audiokit v5-main

Tags: ios, midi, audiokit, sysex

For my ipadOS app I recently switched from audiokit v5-develop (dating from before the official v5 release) to v5-main, and this seems to have broken the ability to receive sysex messages. At least on ipadOS 14.6.

the function **receivedMIDISystemCommand(...)** is not called when receiving a sysex message, but in debug mode I do see a lot of messages like the following appear in console:

```
021-06-08 16:18:09.219252+0200 Rage[990:364326] [midi] MIDI+Receiving.swift:processUMPSysExMessage(with:):246:UMP SYSEX - Continue receiving UMP SysEx messages (MIDI+Receiving.swift:processUMPSysExMessage(with:):246)
```

I assume this means Audiokit is receiving the sysex, but does not call **receivedMIDISystemCommand(...)**.
I can't find any related changes in the docs, any thoughts about what could be wrong here?

thanks!!

Comment: There was no intentional break of syses for sure, but if you could write a test ideally or at least a public example project, that would help us track this down.

Comment: I will do that. Would it help if I would find out in which commit it stopped working? I now checked out a pre-release commit of v5, which made it work again. I noticed the first official v5 release did not work, so something happend in between these points.

Comment: Hi @AureliusProchazka sorry for the extreme delay due to personal circumstances. I have created the example app, using the lates audiokit release. I have uploaded it here: https://github.com/MaartenWL/Audiokit-Receiving-Midi-Example.  The readme file contains my tests results: I show the console messages as they show up when sending a program change message over Bluetooth, en over USB to show USB MIDI data is received, but does not trigger the midilistener.  The